# how to customize xml headers

Tags: activejdbc, export-to-xml, javalite

I have a resultSet formed by:

```
LazyList<DeliveryLabel> deliveryLabels = DeliveryLabel.findBySQL(sql);
String wxml = deliveryLabels.toXml(true, true);
```

The xml generated start with:

```
<delivery_labels>
  <delivery_label>
    <data>
  </delivery_label>
</delivery_labels>
```

how to generate only:

```
<labels>
  <label>
    <data>
  </label>
</labels>
```

I´m can´t rename the class to Label.java, because it already exists in the project.

[]´s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently ActiveJDBC uses [Inflections](http://javalite.io/english_inflections) to pick names for XML tags. If you need custom tags or structure, you will have to implement a custom `toXml()` method.